# Loop two lines and print horizontally from csv file in bash

Tags: bash

I have been trying to print two lines from the csv file to print horizontally and loop the next two lines and try to do the same.

The code which I have tried is

```
while IFS=, read -r name code;
do
echo "$name" "$code" | head -2 | tr ' '
done <  csvfile.csv
```

The csv file contains

```
Albany, N.Y
Albuquerque, N.M.
Anchorage, Alaska
Asheville, N.C.
Atlanta, Ga.
Atlantic City, N.J.
```

All I want is the output like

```
Albany, N.Y.    Albuquerque, N.M.
Anchorage. Alaska.
Asheville, N.C. Atlanta, Ga.
```

and so on

Can anyone help me with this. I have tried different ways as suggested online but still no luck and am a newbie in bash scripting. Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your `echo` only produces a single line of output; piping that to `head` to limit to the first two lines of that will never do anything useful.

Comment: Please fix your question to match output of Ed's answer.

Comment: @Cyrus editted now..sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subject says "loop 3 lines" but the text in your question says "loop 2 lines" and it's not clear what the formula would be to get the output you say you want from the input you posted so... is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ paste - - < csvfile.csv
Albany, N.Y     Albuquerque, N.M.
Anchorage, Alaska       Asheville, N.C.
Atlanta, Ga.    Atlantic City, N.J.
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR%2{p=$0; next} {print p, $0}' csvfile.csv
Albany, N.Y     Albuquerque, N.M.
Anchorage, Alaska       Asheville, N.C.
Atlanta, Ga.    Atlantic City, N.J.
```

It's trivial control whether a tab or blank or any other delimiter appears between columns with either command of course.

See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to do..sorry for the misunderstanding in the subject and thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

With `pr(1)`

```
pr -ta2 file.csv
```

If `ed(1)` is available/acceptable.

```
printf '%s\n' ',s/$/ /' 'g/./j' ',s/ $//' ,p Q | ed -s file.csv
```